# How can I get the maximum and minimum value of a record in Algolia?

Tags: php, algolia

I am using the algolia api to do a product search, where $value is what the customer searches for.

$results = $index->search($value);

In the product registry, for example, I have the fields: name, price, stock, etc. I want to know if there is any way to give me the maximum and minimum value among all the searched products, as well as in mysql where I can use MIN(price) and MAX(price) in a table

I don't want to call all the records and then obtain the maximum and minimum value with php since if there are thousands of products that it returns, the search would be very slow

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; and B) SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name; and C) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "tbl_name"; for analysis.  Do you have flexibility to add indexes to the table in question?